# Spotify/Sonos integration

Tags: spotify, sonos

Apologies if this is the incorrect place to ask such a thing, however I was directed here by the Spotify CS Twitter account.

I was wondering if there was any possibility of the API's on Spotify that allow access to Your Music, Radio features etc would be opened up so that they could be incorportated into the Sonos Controller at all?

It would be a very worthwhile thing to have

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Sonos apps have Spotify already built in, which means you can login to your Spotify account from "Add Music Services" and access your personal spotify config. Unfortunately only if you have premium account. 
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: "Sonos apps have Spotify already built in" means that a custom integration via Programmed Radios can't attain same functionality and design? I can't seem to make a Spotify-inspired home screen working only by following the docs. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you or somebody else from Sonos developer team clarify this aspect please? There are 2 other stackoverflow posts related to this same aspect, one from '17 and the other from '18, that both don't have closure, the issue remaining an enigma up to this day. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43210221/14273827
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926408/14273827

Answer (score 0):

The Spotify Web API does already expose users' [Your Music collection](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/library-endpoints/). Radio functionality isn't exposed though. I don't have enough insight to give you any answers regarding the Sonos Controller unfortunately.