# Customising the SONOS root browse container

Tags: sonos

The documentation currently available in Sonos Labs ([Customising the Root Browse Container](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/478)) states that it can either use the EDITORIAL, GRID or LIST DisplayMode.

Is there any documentation available on how to achieve the display that Apple and Spotify use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in highlighting your brand inside the Sonos app experience. Our partners are critical to our efforts to deliver joy to our listeners. We are excited to help partners find opportunities to shine on Sonos.

The first examples of custom branding on Sonos have been custom work. We know that this is important to our partners, and are working to make it a more self-service part of our platform. We cannot offer it as an option for an integration yet.

Comment: I see that in 2018 (so 1 year later than your comment), on another post, a Sonos developer responds that "We are currently developing the documentation for this experience and will post to our documentation as soon as it becomes available." Please, any update on this? Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926408/14273827