# Unknown (undocumented) SONOS display type used in Spotify music-service on mobile devices

Tags: sonos

Even though there are already 2 other questions on the subject ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108098/customising-the-sonos-root-browse-container) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904812/sonos-music-service-custom-home-screen-like-spotify)), no documentation have yet been provided by somebody from Sonos developer team.

The problem still remains: *how one can attain a similar customised Spotify-like display type on Sonos mobile controller app*. I'm talking about the root container of the Spotify music-service. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsSjt.png).

whereas the documentation clearly only talks about the grid, list, hero and editorial display types, none of which being the one used in Spotify music-service integration. Take a look:

- [grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z96X2.png)
- [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7czWi.png)
- [hero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuFku.png)
- [editorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTUKx.png)

The above 2 other questions I mentioned indicate that, as of April '18, Sonos developer team was working on enabling this experience, but, after almost 2 years, there is nothing AFAIK.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Sonos seem to have given up on developer support here. Spotify uses non-public features of SMAPI to customize its home screen, based on json instead of SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Spotify uses a different **capability** flag for this. In the music services discovery you can fetch from the player. You see they provide a json manifest.

As explained [here](https://github.com/svrooij/node-sonos-ts/tree/master/src/musicservices), I suspect the capabilities field is a bitmask, where you can store one or more booleans in a single integer. You just have to figure out which one says, extended metadata (and send a PR on the documentation).

```
 {
"Name": "Spotify",
"Version": "1.1",
"Uri": "https://spotify-v5.ws.sonos.com/smapi",
"SecureUri": "https://spotify-v5.ws.sonos.com/smapi",
"ContainerType": "MService",
"Capabilities": "5310995",
"Manifest": {
  "Version": "12",
  "Uri": "https://mnfts.ws.sonos.com/p/spotify-manifest.5.json"
},
"Id": 9,
"Policy": {
  "Auth": "AppLink",
  "PollInterval": 300
}
},
```

Other services should be able to provide a similar experience.

I’m not connected to Sonos, I just written a extensive [documentation page](https://sonos.svrooij.io) about local control off Sonos speakers.