# Sonos music service custom home screen like Spotify

Tags: sonos

There is a option to customizing root node with EDITORIAL, GRID, or LIST using presentation map like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Presentation>
    . . .
    <PresentationMap type="DisplayType">
        <RootNodeDisplayType>
            <DisplayMode>GRID</DisplayMode>
        </RootNodeDisplayType>
        . . .
    </PresentationMap>
    . . .
</Presentation>
```

But how show screen like below 
[image: spotify home screen]

Answer (score 0):

We are currently developing the documentation for this experience and will post to our documentation as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: Any update on when it will become available? It's been almost 3 years since your last update. Thank you in advance!